# .Net maui radio button checked changed event not firing with control template

Tags: radio-button, maui, controltemplate

I am using radio button control with customised radio button selection colors in .Net Maui.But when changing the selection , it doesn't fire CheckedChanged event.

Here is the code snippet,

**View**

```
<StackLayout
                x:Name="SexRadioGroup"
                Grid.Row="10"
                Margin="24,12,0,0"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="SexRadioGroup"
                Spacing="40">
                <RadioButton
                    GroupName="SexRadioGroup"
                    IsChecked="True"
                    Value="Male">
                    <RadioButton.Content>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label
                                Margin="30,0,0,0"
                                Text="Male"
                                TextColor="{StaticResource FieldNameTextColor}"
                                VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </RadioButton.Content>
                </RadioButton>

                <RadioButton
                    CheckedChanged="SexRadioButton_CheckedChanged"
                    GroupName="SexRadioGroup"
                    Value="Female">
                    <RadioButton.Content>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label
                                Margin="30,0,0,0"
                                Text="Female"
                                TextColor="{StaticResource FieldNameTextColor}"
                                VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </RadioButton.Content>
                </RadioButton>
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind file

```
private void SexRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

**Style(RadioButton template)**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
        <Frame
            Padding="0"
            BackgroundColor="#F3F2F1"
            BorderColor="#F3F2F1"
            HasShadow="False"
            HeightRequest="100"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            WidthRequest="100">
            <Grid Margin="4" WidthRequest="100">
                <Grid
                    HeightRequest="18"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    WidthRequest="18">
                    <Ellipse
                        Fill="White"
                        HeightRequest="16"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Stroke="Blue"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        WidthRequest="16" />
                    <Ellipse
                        x:Name="check"
                        Fill="Blue"
                        HeightRequest="8"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        WidthRequest="8" />
                </Grid>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#FF3300" />
                                <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Frame>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}" />
    </Style>
```

Is there any way to use renderer to change the selection and unselection color of the radio button by renderers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is the clicked event has been dealt with by the Frame, not the radio button. So you can add the `TapGestureRecognizer` to the Frame. I use the control template in the App.xaml. Such as:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
                <Frame
            Padding="0"
            BackgroundColor="#F3F2F1"
            BorderColor="#F3F2F1"
            HasShadow="False"
            HeightRequest="100"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            WidthRequest="100">
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```

And in the App.cs:

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            Frame frame = sender as Frame;
            RadioButton button = (RadioButton)frame.Parent;
            button.IsChecked = true;
    }
```

And then, the radio button checked changed event will be hit when you click it.  (**Note**: On the windows platform, it can work without the TapGestureRecognizer.)